# Adding a comma to this foreach loop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wanting to separate these links that are outputted by a comma, but with no comma on the last link. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
<p class="favs">Favourite Courses: 
                <?php 
                    $user_id = bp_get_member_user_id();
                    $array = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wpfp_favorites', true); 

                    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                    $queried_post = get_post($value); ?>

                    <a href="http://publicaccessgolf.com.au/<?php echo $queried_post->post_name; ?>" title="<?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?>" ><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></a>

                 <?php } ?>
                </p>
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way is typically this:

```
$links = array();
foreach (...) {
    $links[] = '<a ...';
}

echo join(', ', $links);
```

Adapt to your situation as appropriate.

Comment: `implode` = `join`, just saying. :)

Comment: That is not working. I am taking the values (post id) from the array and using these values to get the post URL and title. So I need to echo out the URL and title, not the values from the array. If that makes sense? (probably not :)

Comment: @user Ever heard of string concatenation? `"string" . $variable . "string"`

Comment: @deceze I have heard of string concatenation. How does that help what I am trying to do though?

Comment: Take a good look again at my answer. Instead of `echo`ing out all the links and titles directly, *put them into an array `$links` first*. You make a new array. When you have an array full of such links and titles, output them using `join`, which puts in the right number of commas.